# Sat problem about math

Tags: inequality

Given: $$-\frac{12}{5}<6-9y<-\frac{9}{4}.$$

In the inequality above, what is one possible value of $3y-2$?

Comment: What is your trying?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{3}{4}<3y-2<\frac{4}{5}.$$
$0.76$ is valid.